# Twyton / Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-install-ui3eeW/twython/

Tags: python-2.7, pip

here is my problem ;(
i use ist with my raspi pi pip

ive this version installed of pip

"
pip 18.1 from /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip (python 2.7)
"

```
pi@adsb:~ $ git clone git://github.com/ryanmcgrath/twython.git
Cloning into 'twython'...
remote: Enumerating objects: 68, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (68/68), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (55/55), done.
remote: Total 3690 (delta 24), reused 29 (delta 12), pack-reused 3622
Receiving objects: 100% (3690/3690), 2.72 MiB | 3.35 MiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (1992/1992), done.
pi@adsb:~ $ cd twython
pi@adsb:~/twython $ python setup.py install
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "setup.py", line 33, in <module>
    long_description=open('README.md', encoding='utf-8').read() + '\n\n' +open('HISTORY.md', encoding='utf-8').read                                                                                                                                                                                                          (),
TypeError: 'encoding' is an invalid keyword argument for this function
pi@adsb:~/twython $ sudo apt-get install python-setuptools python-pip
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
python-setuptools is already the newest version (40.8.0-1).
python-pip is already the newest version (18.1-5+rpt1).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 3 not upgraded.
pi@adsb:~/twython $ sudo pip install twython
Looking in indexes: https://pypi.org/simple, https://www.piwheels.org/simple
Collecting twython
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/b7/2c/fb17cb309fccd4e63638715325768bd959b0ad78b23b0cbc0738f5                                                                                                                                                                                                          fc8c58/twython-3.8.2.tar.gz
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/tmp/pip-install-ui3eeW/twython/setup.py", line 33, in <module>
        long_description=open('README.md', encoding='utf-8').read() + '\n\n' +open('HISTORY.md', encoding='utf-8').                                                                                                                                                                                                          read(),
    TypeError: 'encoding' is an invalid keyword argument for this function

    ----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-install-ui3eeW/twython/
```

any ideas?
So i cant use it as an twitterclient :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> `open('README.md', encoding='utf-8')`

`encoding` was added to `open()` at Python 3.0. Hence the code requires Python 3+. If you really need Python 2.7 use older `twython`. Version 3.7.0 seems to be ok:

```
pip install twython==3.7.0
```

Comment: THX, that was the problem now it works ;)